# Call to ActionResponse.setRenderParam is ignored / ineffective

Tags: jsf, liferay, portlet

I have a Liferay JSF 2.0 portlet that has code like the following:

```
private String userId
private String organization
private String registrationToken

...

public String submitLogin() {
    ActionResponse actionResponse = (ActionResponse) PortletUtil.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("userId", this.userId);
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("org", this.organization);

    if ( StringUtils.hasText(this.registrationToken) )
        actionResponse.setRenderParameter("token", this.registrationToken);

    ...
}
```

All of the private member variables are mapped to input form fields and have the appropriate getters and setters.

If I trace this code in Eclipse's debugger and examine the contents of the ActionResponse instance's _publicRenderParameters HashMap, I see that the userId and org params have been set just fine. Stepping through the next lines, I see that the registrationToken has the correct submitted hidden input value, and the last setRenderParameter() call is being made.

Here's the Bizarro World part: After that last setRenderParameter() call, there is absolutely no update to the _publicRenderParameters HashMap in the ActionResponse and the token stubbornly stays un-set in the params.

I've tried multiple ways to make it work, from passing the token through a session-scoped bean we've used for holding other params; to calling setRenderParameter() later in the code flow (still using the same ActionResponse reference); to using a different key name ("registrationToken") on the call, just in case "token" was some kind of reserved name or something. Nothing has gotten this last call to actually update the map.

I've also Googled every combination of relevant terms I can think of, but haven't found anything like this particular issue.

Has anyone else run into this problem? I'm at my wits end why ActionResponse's param map updates fine on the first two calls but not this last one.

= Joe =

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to develop a login type of portlet, then you might want to look at the [jsf2-login-portlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces/tree/3.1.2-ga3/demos/portal/jsf2-login-portlet) demo.

Answer (score 0):

Got in touch with one of my team members this morning, he saw the problem right away. Note that when I was debugging, I saw the user ID and organization values being set in the ActionResponse's _public_render_params Map. That was actually the key. My token value **was** being set, but I was looking in the wrong member variable. The value was set as a **private** render param in the ActionResponse's _params Map.

The actual fix was to add a public render param definition in the portlet.xml, and then make that new public render param supported in the above portlet along with the next one in the sequence.

Under the `<portlet-app>` tag I needed:

```
<public-render-parameter>
    <identifier>registrationToken</identifier>
    <qname xmlns:x="http://liferay.com/pub-renderparams">x:registrationToken</qname>
</public-render-parameter>
```

Then in the relevant `<portlet>` tag I had to add:

```
<supported-public-render-parameter>registrationToken</supported-public-render-parameter>
```

I used "registrationToken" rather than token just for clarity. Once that was done, I updated the setRenderParam() call to use key "registrationToken" instead of "token", and everything started to work as expected.